# how to show data in textbox in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have problem in this code. When I press "show button" I want data from database shows in text box and "modify" and "delete" buttons work.
But in this code when I press show button it shows error `Notice: Undefined index: first_name`, I am stuck in this code. How to resolve this?

```
        include '../../../../database/dbConnection.php';

        //-------------------------------------------
        $row[0]="";
$isSaveDisabled = true;
$isCreateDisabled=false;
$isModifyDiasbled=true;
$isDeleteDisabled=true;


                                if (isset ($_POST['create_button'])) {

                                $isSaveDisabled = false;
                                $isCreateDisabled=true;

                                $sql="select ifnull(max(user_id),10000)+1 from user_master";
                                $res=  mysql_query($sql);
                                $row=  mysql_fetch_array($res);
                                 $row[0];



           }
           if(isset($_POST['modify_button']))
               {

               }
           if(isset($_POST['delete_button']))
               {

               }
        ?>

<!--
        PHP CODE ENDS FROM HERE-------------------------
        -->
        <!--
        BOOTSTRAP START FROM HERE-------------------------
        -->
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../bootStrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../bootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../css/StyleSheet.css">
        <script src="../../../../js/ValidateKeyPress.js"></script>

        <title></title>
        <script>

</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
<!--        <div class="page-header1">
        Hello
        </div>-->
        <div class="container jumbotron  ">
        <div class=" text-center"><h4>USER CREATION</h4></div>

        <form class="form-inline " action="" method="POST" name="myForm">
            <div class="form-group1">

        <label class="control-label" for="ec" id="myID">ENTITY CODE</label>
        <select class="form-control2" name="ecode" id="myID">
        <option value="">SELECT ENTITY CODE</option>   
        <option>DOC</option>
        <option>EMP</option>
        <option>NUR</option>
        <option>ORG</option>
        <option>TEC</option>
        <option>VEN</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group1">
        <label class="control-label" for="uid">USER ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control2" name="userid" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>">
        </div> 
          <hr>     
        <table class="table1 table-borderless table-responsive">

        <tbody>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['select_button']))
    {
    $qrydatabind='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
          number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
          email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER ORDER BY user_id DESC 
          LIMIT 1';
                  $results1=  mysql_query($qrydatabind) or die(mysql_error());

                      while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results1 ) ) {

    }
    }
?>
        <tr>

          <th scope="row"></th>
         <td><label class="control-label" for="finame" id="myID1" >FIRST NAME</label></td>
        <td><input value="<?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?>"  type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase"name="firstname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);" ></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="mname">MIDDLE NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="middlename"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="lname" id="myID2">LAST NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="  form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="lastname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="fname">FATHER NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="fathername"></td>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="moname">MOTHER NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="mothername"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="nod">NO.OF DEPENDENTS</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="nod"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="dob" id="myID3">D.O.B</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"  id="myID3" ></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="gen" id="myID4">GENDER</label></td>

        <td><select id="myID4" class="form-control2" name="gender">
        <option value="">SELECT GENDER</option> 
        <option>M</option>
        <option>F</option>
        <option>o</option>

        </select></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="idm">IDENTIFICATION MARK</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="idmark"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="ms">MARITAL STATUS</label></td>

        <td><select class=" form-control2" name="mstatus">
        <option value="">SELECT STATUS</option> 
        <option>M</option>
        <option>U</option>


        </select></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="sname">SPOUSE NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="spname"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="mno" id="myID5">MOBILE NO.</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="mobileno" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return allnumeric(event);"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="em">EMAIL-ID</label></td>
          <td><input  id="myID6" type="text" class="form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="email" placeholder="sample@gmail.com"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="adhar">ADHAR-ID</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="adharid"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="paname">PAN NUMBER</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="pannumber"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td><label  class="control-label" for="passno">PASSPORT NO.</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="passportno"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="tno">TIN NUMBER</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="tinnumber"></td>
        <td><label  class="control-label" for="dno">DL NUMBER</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="dlnumber"></td>
        </tr>


        </tbody>
        </table>


          <div class="btn-group-sm2 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name="create_button" <?php echo $isCreateDisabled?'disabled':'';?>>CREATE</button>

        <?php
  if($isCreateDisabled) {
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID").style.color = "red";</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID1").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID2").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID3").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID4").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID5").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>'; 
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("myID6").style.color = "#ff0000";</script>';    

  }
?>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="modify_button"<?php echo $isModifyDiasbled?'disabled':'';?>>MODIFY</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="delete_button" <?php echo $isDeleteDisabled?'disabled':'';?>>DELETE</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="clear_button">CLEAR</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " name="save_button" <?php echo $isSaveDisabled?'disabled':''; ?> onclick="return validateForm();">SAVE</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="exit_button">EXIT</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-right" name="search_button">SEARCH</button>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-right" name="select_button">SHOW</button>
        </div>
        </form>

        </div>

      </tbody>

      <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">


               <?php
        if(isset($_POST['save_button'])){
        $isCreateDisabled=false;
                if(isset($_POST['ecode']) && isset($_POST['firstname'])&& isset($_POST['middlename'])&& isset($_POST['lastname'])
                && isset($_POST['fathername'])&& isset($_POST['mothername'])&& isset($_POST['nod']) && isset($_POST['dob'])
                && isset($_POST['gender'])&& isset($_POST['idmark'])&& isset($_POST['mstatus'])&& isset($_POST['spname'])
                && isset($_POST['mobileno'])&& isset($_POST['email'])&& isset($_POST['adharid'])&& isset($_POST['pannumber'])
                && isset($_POST['passportno'])&& isset($_POST['tinnumber'])&& isset($_POST['dlnumber']))
                   {
                           $ecode=$_POST['ecode']; $first_name=$_POST['firstname']; $middle_name=$_POST['middlename'];
                           $last_name=$_POST['lastname']; $father_name=$_POST['fathername']; $mother_name=$_POST['mothername'];  
                           $number_of_dependents=$_POST['nod'];  $dob=$_POST['dob']; $gender=$_POST['gender'];
                           $identification_mark=$_POST['idmark']; $marital_status=$_POST['mstatus'];
                           $spouse_name=$_POST['spname']; $mobile_number=$_POST['mobileno']; $email_id=$_POST['email'];
                           $adhar_id=$_POST['adharid'];$pan_number=$_POST['pannumber'];  $passport_number=$_POST['passportno'];
                           $tin_number=$_POST['tinnumber']; $dl_number=$_POST['dlnumber'];


                   }

                                  $qry="insert into user_master(ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
                                  number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
                                  email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number)
                                  VALUES('$ecode','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$father_name','$mother_name',
                                      '$number_of_dependents',str_to_date('$dob','%d/%m/%Y'),'$gender','$identification_mark','$marital_status',
                                          '$spouse_name','$mobile_number','$email_id','$adhar_id','$pan_number',
                                              '$passport_number','$tin_number','$dl_number')";
                           $resultss=  mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
                           if($resultss)
                               {
                               echo "<script>
                                      alert('SuccessFully');
                                        </script>";

                               }
                               else
                                   {
                                   return "Error...! Not Inserted.";
                                   }
          $qrydatabind='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
          number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
          email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER ORDER BY user_id DESC 
          LIMIT 1';
                  $results=  mysql_query($qrydatabind) or die(mysql_error());

                      while( $row =  mysql_fetch_array( $results ) ) {
                        echo
            "
                <div class='table-responsive'>
<table  border='1' style= 'background-color: #84ed86; color: #761a9b;  ' >
      <thead>
                <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>Entity Code</th>
              <th>User Id</th> <th>User Name</th> <th>Father Name</th>  <th>Mother Name</th>  <th>No.Of Dependents</th>
              <th>D.O.B</th> <th>GENDER</th> <th>Id Mark</th> <th>MARITAL STATUS</th>  <th>SPOUSE NAME</th>
              <th>Mob. Number</th> <th>E-Id</th> <th>ADHAR-ID</th> <th>PAN-No.</th> <th>PASSPORT-No.</th>
               <th>TIN-NO.</th> <th>DL-No.</th>
            </tr>
                </thead>

                      <tr >        

                        <td> </td> 
                        <td>{$row['ecode']}</td> <td> echo $row[0];</td>
                        <td>{$row['first_name']} {$row['middle_name']} {$row['last_name']}</td>             
                        <td>{$row['father_name']}</td> <td>{$row['mother_name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['number_of_dependents']}</td> <td>{$row['dob']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['gender']}</td> <td>{$row['identification_mark']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['marital_status']}</td> <td>{$row['spouse_name']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td> <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['adhar_id']}</td>  <td>{$row['pan_number']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['passport_number']}</td> <td>{$row['tin_number']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['dl_number']}</td>


            </tr> </table>  
              </div>";
        }}


        ?>
    </table>

      </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please edit code. Cannot read it. Remove code that doesnt pertain to problem too please. TY

Comment: This is a **why isn't this code working?** question. Update your question to tell us your **specific** error and which **section** of code is causing it. Please consider your readability, also.

Comment: Which line is the warning coming from?

Comment: <td><input value="<?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?>"  type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase"name="firstname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);" ></td>

Comment: this line show error, undefined index-firstname

Answer (score 0):

If edits and delete work that means your select statement is wrong. Maybe u are not properly declaring your fields in your select statement. Id look into that first. What I do when my sql is on error is open up an sql session and try doing the query straight from the sql editor.

Also,

why are you using limit 1? You are fetching a result of records for an array but you are limiting your query to one row?

**EDIT:**

Dont you have to select user_id in order to use ORDER BY? All you have to do is add user_id to select statement

Comment: because i want when i press show button then only one record came in textbox

Comment: Gotcha. Can you pull up an sql tool from command line? Id enter the query from command line and see if you get any results.

Comment: user_id is your problem

Comment: ok friend i will r&d again on my code

Comment: Add user_id to select statement. If works please mark answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: ok friend, thanks for you help